# Quick action on Community

Tags: community, quickaction

Currently we decided instead of duplicatin fields from another object to use quick action with lookup field.

[image][image]For all users its working fine, but when we want it in community, it's no appearing at all :O . I tried permissions , but still not appearing at all.
Usage - On Financial account I have created "Update a record" action and selected fields to its layout. After on Insurance object by lookup field I am connecting  update record with this on Financial account, by this I can link on insurance policy according financial account on one layout and see field which were set in action layout.

So basically what I intended.. For communities I need same as this solution. That mean that on one object I will have option to show related accounts with fields I can choose. ( sometimes its 6 or 15 fields depending on record type. )

[image]

As I understand this feature is still not avialable for Communities. Is there any different way how to show direct fields from another record on different object depending on record type?

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZyvUAF/pass-a-value-other-than-recordid-to-a-lightning-component-in-a-community

Comment: I'm not clear what the "Quick Action" is doing, but if it is simply showing the value of a field on a related object, why not use a cross-object formula field?

Comment: @PhilW This quick action has layout with fields with component - related record. We want to avoid creating new fields, because than they want same API name for them and it's causing deploy error for another 4 environmenst, because it will be like 15 another fields.

Comment: I personally cannot help since I still don't have a clear idea what you're doing. Perhaps you could [edit] the question to add specific detail as to how the "quick action" is configured, what it should look like, references to documentation you followed etc.? It may be that someone else would understand already, but the more (relevant) info you provide in the question the better in general (just not tl;dr!).

Comment: @PhilW I edited situation how it is.,